# Recursive function finding all subset

Tags: python, recursion, subset

I need to implement the recursive function (k, n(subsets_size_k) which accepts 2 integers n and k, and returns as a list the subsets of size k of the group {1, 2 ... n} in some order.
Each subset in the circled list will be represented by A string of subset members.
All characters of the string representing a subgroup must be in ascending order from left to right.
We can Assume that 0<= k <= n and 1<= n <= 9.

Examples:
For the call (3, 5(subsets_size_k) the list will be returned (up to a change in the order of the strings representing subsets):
['123', '124', '125', '134', '135', '145', '234', '235', '245', '345']
For the call (0, 5(subsets_size_k) the list with the empty string will be returned: ['']

For each string, the characters of the string must be in ascending order. So for example, the string '342' which represents the sub
The group {2, 3, 4} will not be accepted, and the representative string that will be accepted is '234.

I am not allowed to use methods or loops or functions, except "len"

that's what i'v tried:

```
    def k_sum_subset(n, k):
        if k == 0:
            return []
        if k == 1:
            return base_case(n)
        return k_sum_subset(n, k-1) + k_sum_subset(n-1, k-1)
    

    def base_case(n):
        if n == 1:
            return [1]
        if n == 2:
            return [[1], [2]]
        if n == 3:
            return [[1], [2], [3]]
        if n == 4:
            return [[1], [2], [3], [4]]
        if n == 5:
            return [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]
        if n == 6:
            return [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]]
        if n == 7:
            return [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7]]
        if n == 8:
            return [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8]]
        if n == 9:
            return [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9]] `
```

i'v tried to print (k_sum_subset(5, 3))
and that was the result:

```
    [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [1], [2], [3], [4], [1], [2], [3], [4], [1], [2], [3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you are writing is too complex and time consuming. First, you should take the input from the user as n and k, which can be any digit from 1 to nine:

```
n = int(input("Enter the value of n: "))
k = int(input("Enter the value of k: "))
```

then create a function for showing subsets:

```
def subsets_size_k(n, k):
    """
    Recursive func to find all possible subsets of size k for the set {1, 2, ..., n}.
    """
    if k == 0:
        # it also checks if the set is empty it will return null or empty set
        return [set()]
    elif n < k:
        # and if there are no subsets of size k for n<k, it will also return []
        return []
    else:
        # find all subsets of size k-1 for {1 to n-1}
        subsets = subsets_size_k(n-1, k-1)
        # Add n to each subset of size k-1 to get all subsets of size k for {1 to n}
        subsets_with_n = [{n} | subset for subset in subsets]
        # Combine the subsets of size k-1 and k to get size of subset
        return subsets_size_k(n-1, k) + subsets_with_n
```

After this, the function must be called:

```
subsets = subsets_size_k(n, k)
```

and then print the answer the way you want:

```
print(f" All subsets of size {k} for the set {{1 to {n}}}:", subsets)
```

If you want to use the switch statement and cases you can simply change the if else if conditions to case and print result in default or show empty in it.  Here is all the code on one block:

```
def subsets_size_k(n, k):
    """
    Recursive func to find all possible subsets of size k for the set {1, 2, ..., n}.
    """
    if k == 0:
        # it also checks if the set is empty it will return null or empty set
        return [set()]
    elif n < k:
        # and if there are no subsets of size k for n<k, it will also return []
        return []
    else:
        # find all subsets of size k-1 for {1 to n-1}
        subsets = subsets_size_k(n-1, k-1)
        # Add n to each subset of size k-1 to get all subsets of size k for {1 to n}
        subsets_with_n = [{n} | subset for subset in subsets]
        # Combine the subsets of size k-1 and k to get size of subset
        return subsets_size_k(n-1, k) + subsets_with_n
k = int(input("Enter the value of k: "))
n = int(input("Enter the value of n: "))
subsets = subsets_size_k(n, k)
print(f" All subsets of size {k} for the set {{1 to {n}}}:", subsets)
```

Answer (score 0):

If a generator expression doesn't count as a "loop" and is therefore allowed:

```
def k_sum_subset(n, k):
    def _k_sum_subset(n, k):
        if k == 0:
            yield ''
        else:
            if n > k:
                yield from _k_sum_subset(n - 1, k)
            yield from (f'{s}{n}' for s in _k_sum_subset(n - 1, k - 1))
    return [*_k_sum_subset(n, k)]
```

EDIT: Now that you've clarified your requirements by stating that `for` and `yield` keywords are disallowed, you can create a helper function to "iterate" through a sequence by recursion instead, and make the function return a list directly:

```
def append_for_each(n, lst):
    return ['%s%d' % (lst[0], n)] + append_for_each(n, lst[1:]) if lst else []

def k_sum_subset(n, k):
    return (
        (k_sum_subset(n - 1, k) if n > k else []) +
        append_for_each(n, k_sum_subset(n - 1, k - 1))
    ) if k else ['']
```

so that `k_sum_subset(5, 3)` returns:

```
['123', '124', '134', '234', '125', '135', '235', '145', '245', '345']
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/HonestStormyLine

Comment: Thank you. just one question, what " [f'{list[0]}{n}'] " means? I didn't encountered this before.

Comment: The `f'...'` syntax is called an f-string, as documented in [PEP-498](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/). If this is not yet covered in your course either, you can use the more traditional [string formatting operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting) `%` to format a number into a string, as I have revised my answer above. This is done to avoid calling the `str` function to convert the number into a string, which I believe is disallowed by your question since you said only the `len` function is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Used an envelope function *helper* which called by your *k_sum_subsets*:

```
def helper(n, k, st):
    result = []
    if len(st) == k:
        result.append(st)
    elif len(st) < k and n > 0:
        result += helper(n - 1, k, st)
        result += helper(n - 1, k, str(n) + st)
    return result


def k_size_subsets(n, k):
    return helper(n, k, '')
```

- It first initializes an empty list - *result*. If the length of the
  current string *st* is equal to *k*, it means we have found a valid
  subset of size *k* -> append it to *result*.
- Otherwise, if the length of *st* is less than *k* and *n* is greater
  than 0, we make two recursive calls to *helper* - one with the same
  string *st*, and one with *n* "stringed" to the beginning of *st*.
  The results from both recursive calls are appended to *result*.

For the call:

```
print(k_size_subsets(5, 3))
print(k_size_subsets(6, 4))
```

Output is:

```
['123', '124', '134', '234', '125', '135', '235', '145', '245', '345']
['1234', '1235', '1245', '1345', '2345', '1236', '1246', '1346', '2346', 
 '1256', '1356', '2356', '1456', '2456', '3456']
```